# Organizing data in frame

Tags: r, dataframe

So... I've got some data coming to me in small batches, in spreadsheets.  I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to put this information into a `data.frame` in R for later analysis.

An example of what I get would be something like this:

```
-----------------------------------
|  Component combination A+B+C    |
-----------------------------------
|     |  Meter  |  RCBS  |  AND   |
-----------------------------------
|  1  |  2509   |  2486  |  2535  |
-----------------------------------
|  2  |  2435   |  2484  |  2539  |
-----------------------------------
|  3  |  2507   |  2493  |  2565  |
-----------------------------------
|  4  |  2558   |  2483  |  2538  |
-----------------------------------
|  5  |  2510   |  2515  |  2530  |
-----------------------------------
```

...where the numbers are repeated individual measurements (runs) using the listed component combination, with one of the components dispensed using one of three different devices ("Meter", etc.).  There would typically be ~20 values in each column.

Should I be going for a wide or long format when I put this data into a frame?  Do I want the data in the rows or in the columns?

Comment: These seems like a very subjective question.  I think the answer depends on what you would like to do with it specifically.

Comment: I thought it might.  In this particular instance, I want to run comparisons between the sets of numbers under 'Meter', 'RCBS' and 'AND'.  Test for normality, compare the means, variances, etc. if that helps.  And then compare between other combinations as well.

Comment: You'll want the data in long format to run regression.  Depending on what you're familiar with in R, you can use either wide or long format for tests for normality and summary statistics.